# Tensorflow 2.x: Processing list with different-shaped tensors in tf.function using tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, control-flow

Currently I am trying to reshape a not-directly known number of different-shaped tensors. The problem is, that the function is tagged with @tf.function to create a graph (the whole problem is part of a neural network, where the performance boost with @tf.function regarding the runtime per epoch is essential).

For this question the network returns two tensors with shape_1=[15,1] and shape_2=[12,1]. The tensors should be processed by a further Layer, reshaped, afterwards stored in a TensorArray and then concated in the first dimension. The code example - a first idea of mine - is shown below (without the processing of the layer, but the error is the same):

```
  @tf.function
  def fct(inputs_1):

    def tf_body(inputs, tf_A, tf_number):

        tf_map = tf.gather(inputs, tf_number)
        # processing by layer, e.g tf_map = Layer_1(tf_map)
        # reshaping the result
        tf_map = tf.reshape(tf_map, [-1])

        tf_A = tf_A.write(tf_number, tf_map)
        tf_number +=1

        return inputs, tf_A, tf_number

    tf_number_0 = tf.constant(0)
    tf_arr = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=2, infer_shape=False)
    tf_cond = lambda inputs, tf_arr, tf_number: tf.less(tf_number, 2)

    tf_input, tf_arr, tf_number_0 = tf.while_loop(tf_cond, tf_body, [inputs_1, tf_arr, tf_number_0],\
         shape_invariants=[[tf.TensorShape([None,None]), tf.TensorShape([None,None])], tf.TensorShape([]), tf_number_0.get_shape()], \
              parallel_iterations=1)

    tf_arr = tf_arr.concat()

    return tf_arr

test_P2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[15,1], dtype=tf.float32)
test_P3 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[12,1], dtype=tf.float32)

tf_out = fct([test_P2, test_P3])
```

This code raises following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [15,1] != values[1].shape = [12,1]
         [[{{node while/body/_1/GatherV2/params}}]] [Op:__inference_fct_71]
```

The problem is, that I am not really in the syntax and way of working of tf.while_loop and don't even know, if such approach with a loop could work in tf.function. Especially the argument "shape_invariants" is something, where I am not sure how to use it.

I hope, that someone can help me solving this problem.

Comment: The idea of the code is essentially right I think (some things could be slightly simplified maybe). But the problem is `test_P2` and `test_P3` have different shapes, and you are trying to use `[test_P2, test_P3]` as a single tensor, which doesn't work because tensors with different shapes cannot be stacked into a new one. If you are always going to have a fixed number of tensors, it may be better to simply write your function `fct` as `return tf.concat([tf.reshape(Layer_1(inp), [-1]) for inp in inputs_1], axis=0)`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this solution, it worked pretty well. Yes, the number of tensors stays the same for each epoch. I was just curious if there is a way to iterate through different-shaped tensors with a while loop. But your solution suits really well.